# jQuery mouseover/mouseout on element with children

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have a div with one or more children. When I hover over the parent the child div should show. The problem is that when I hover over the child it hides then shows again. How can I fix this to only hide the child when I stop hovering over the parent.

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/79h3soqu/4/)

```
.parent{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.child{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
.console{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="console"></div>

var hovS = 0;
$('.parent').mouseover(function(){
    if(hovS == 0){
        $('.child').css('display', 'block');
        $('.child').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
        hovS = 1;
    }
    $('.console').append(hovS + ' - ');    
});
$('.parent').mouseout(function(){
    if(hovS == 1){
        $('.child').css('display', 'none');
        $('.child').animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
        hovS = 0;
    }
    $('.console').append(hovS + ' - ');
});
```

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/79h3soqu/4/)

Comment: Try giving the .child element a CSS property of 'pointer-events: none'

Comment: pointer-events works. but this is not a cross browser solution. only works on IE10.

Comment: Does this have to be jQuery? Could you use CSS hover properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are making this way harder than you have to with all the css changes... since you are using jquery why not just do something like this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79h3soqu/5/)

```
$(".parent").hover( function() {
    $(".child").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(".child").fadeOut();
});
```

Also since these are classes it implies there could be multiple parents and children... you might want to change the child selector to something like `$(this).find(".child")...`

---

If you really need the console thing...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79h3soqu/7/)

```
$(".parent").hover( function() {
    $(this).find(".child").fadeIn();
    $(".console").append("1 - ");
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".child").fadeOut();
    $(".console").append("0 - ");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the hover event, it doesn't propogate down to child elements. So it would look something like this:

```
var hovS = 0;
$('.parent').hover(function(){

  if(hovS == 0){
    $('.child').css('display', 'block');
    $('.child').animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
    hovS = 1;
  }
  $('.console').append(hovS + ' - ');    
},function(){
  if(hovS == 1){
    $('.child').css('display', 'none');
    $('.child').animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
    hovS = 0;
  }
  $('.console').append(hovS + ' - ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add stop before your animation.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ogh78zcd/)

Like so:

```
var hovS = 0;
$('.parent').mouseover(function(){
if(hovS == 0){
    $('.child').css('display', 'block');
    $('.child').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
    hovS = 1;
}
$('.console').append(hovS + ' - ');    
});
$('.parent').mouseout(function(){
if(hovS == 1){
    $('.child').css('display', 'none');
    $('.child').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
    hovS = 0;
}
$('.console').append(hovS + ' - ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend smerny's answer; this really is a simple problem.  However, if you really want to animate the opacity, I'd say do it something like this:

```
$('.parent').hover(function() { // use '.hover()', this first function handles the hover-in
    $('.child').css('display', 'block'); // assign this before the animation starts

    $('.child').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400); // use '.stop()' to avoid animation overlaps

}, function() { // this second function handles the hover-out
    $('.child').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 400, function() { // callback function for the animation
        $('.child').css('display', 'none'); // assign this one when the animation is done
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/79h3soqu/6/)